# Is it possible to os.walk 2 different file directories and compare them to each other as it walks through

Tags: python

I know it is possible to iterate over 2 lists in parallel like so...

```
for x, y in zip(xList, yList):
    print x, y
```

Is it possible to do the same with the os.walk function for 2 file directories?

Comment: You can possibly used threads although I have not mastered how to use them so I could not help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not start with `for x, y in zip(*map(os.walk, (dir1, dir2,))): ...`?

Edit: forgot a closing parenthesis

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but the key to making it work is to perform in-place replacement to the sub-directories returned by both generators so that only sub-directories that are common to both of the current directories are retained for deeper traversal and further comparisons; otherwise the sub-directories produced by the two generators won't align with each other with `zip` once there is a sub-directory that's unique to one of them:

```
import os
for (root1, dirs1, files1), (root2, dirs2, files2) in zip(os.walk('dir1'), os.walk('dir2')):
    set1, set2 = set(dirs1), set(dirs2)
    print('Directories unique to {}: {}'.format(root1, set1 - set2))
    print('Directories unique to {}: {}'.format(root2, set2 - set1))
    dirs1[:] = dirs2[:] = set1 & set2 # crucial to retain only the common directories
    set1, set2 = set(files1), set(files2)
    print('Files unique to {}: {}'.format(root1, set1 - set2))
    print('Files unique to {}: {}'.format(root1, set2 - set1))
```

See demo: https://repl.it/repls/WholePessimisticSource

From the documentation of [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

> When `topdown` is `True`, the caller can modify the `dirnames` list in-place
>   (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse
>   into the subdirectories whose names remain in `dirnames`; this can be
>   used to prune the search...